# Mac OS X -- lost all app in Application folder

Tags: macos, terminal

I have a big issue.
I type this command in Terminal app

```
bless --folder /Volumes/Applicaitons --openfolder /Volumes/DIRECTORY
```

After that, all app in Applications disappear. I don't why how to backup all.
Please help me.

Comment: Typo? `/Volumes/Applicaitons` -> `/Volumes/Applications`

Comment: I type bless --folder /Applications/MyApp.app --openfolder /Applications/

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  That looks like a potentially massive mess you've made.  Hopefully you haven't attempted to reboot your machine.

Try doing:

```
bless --folder /System --openfolder /
```

and that *should* reset your blessed folder.

If the Applications folder stays invisible, you can make it visible via:

```
SetFile -a v /Applications
```

(by the way, is "`/Volumes/Applications` -- the name you typed in a panic up in your question -- a valid hard drive volume??  or did you mean "`/Applications`"?)